# Creating a variable to verify if the button event handler was clicked or not

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I have some button event handlers and I need to verify if they are clicked or not. I'm trying to put a bool inside the event, but since there are multiple buttons I need the bool to reset every time it gets out of the event.

I tried putting the bool inside the event, but it only works for a single button:

```
public void verify()
{
    if (this.textBox.Text != null &&
            this.comboBox.Text != null
            && (button bool here)
          )
    {
        tabControl.SelectedIndex = 2;
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter parameters");
    }
}
```

I would like the bool to be false if all of the buttons are not clicked, and true after all of them are clicked at least once.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Form temp = new Form(Image);
    temp.ShowDialog();
    int x = temp.x;
    int y = temp.y;
    int w = temp.w;
    int h = temp.h;
}
```

This is a sample button and there are probably 20 more like this on different pages. Average 4 to 5 buttons on a single page. What's the best possible way to verify the button clicks?

Comment: sounds like you need a collection of bools then, possibly as a bunch of `bool` properties of a class. But there's probably a better way to solve the overall problem. Are all the button click event's connected to the same event handler?

Comment: It's difficult to infer from your post what you want your code to do. Do you want to execute the first `if` statement only if a specific button click called the `verify()` method?

Comment: the verify() method executes at the end of the page and it runs after the label continue (event handler) is clicked. I need to check whether all the buttons are also clicked or not inside the page

Comment: Set the tag property when the button is clicked to a bool value, then use linq to query against all the buttons you need to, to determine if all is true or not... There are many ways to do this, honestly the answers are going to be more than likely opinionated.

Comment: FYI, the `Text` property of a `TextBox` (or a `ComboBox`) will never be `null`.

Comment: That was just an example. I appreciate the correction tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is to encapsulate the `bool` fields into a class that represents the program's state, along with a calculated property that returns `true` if all the other fields are `true`.

For example:

```
class ProgramState
{
    public bool UserAcceptedAgreement { get; set; }
    public bool UserAcknowledgedLiability { get; set; }
    public bool UserSubmittedSignature { get; set; }

    public bool EverythingAccepted =>
        UserSubmittedSignature &&
        UserAcknowledgedLiability &&
        UserSubmittedSignature;
}
```

Then you can create an instance of this class in your `Form` class, and set the properties from the button click events, and in the `Verify` method you can check if they are all true in your `if` statement:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ProgramState programState = new ProgramState();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAcceptAgreement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        programState.UserAcceptedAgreement = true;
    }

    private void btnAcceptLiability_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        programState.UserAcknowledgedLiability = true;
    }

    private void btnSubmitSignature_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        programState.UserSubmittedSignature = true;
    }

    public void verify()
    {
        if (programState.EverythingAccepted)
        {
            tabControl.SelectedIndex = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter parameters");
        }
    }
}
```